# Dynamic Javascript code injection into HTML body

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using Angular JS and all my views are separately split as different HTML template files. Using Angular JS Ui-Router i am changing my views(login.html template is loaded into index.html). One of my html template **(login.html)** has a javascript code . Template is as shown below

```
<div class="app-page app-login" data-page="login">
<div class="app-content">
    <div class="app-section">
        <input class="app-input" placeholder="john.doe@gmail.com">
        <input class="app-input" placeholder="&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;" type="password" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = '&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;'">
        <div class="app-button blue">
            Login
        </div>
        <div class="app-button blue">
            Create Account
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
    Copyrights &#169;
    <script>
        document.write((new Date()).getFullYear());
    </script>
</div>
```

When i change the view the script in the template is not getting executed. What i expect at runtime is **"Copyright @ 2015"**. Is this a known limitation or any hack prevention technique by browsers?

When i place it in my main HTML file its working fine.

Comment: FYI: there's no need to keep renewing your copyright claim every year. Your copyright is not valid on a per-year basis.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use Angular controller to get current year from a $scope variable then print it normal? Like this:
Controller.js

```
$scope.currentYear = (new Date()).getFullYear();
```

view.html

```
<div class="footer">
    Copyrights &#169;{{currentYear}}
</div>
```

Comment: thats the alternate approach. I know about that. I specifically needed to know the answer with the approach i have written.